# Local resolver with PowerDNS and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, dns, resolv.conf

I installed PowerDNS as authoritative server for my domain.

I had to remove **systemd-resolved** package for the installation of **pdns-server** and **pdns-backend-mysql** package.

After the installation, my domain is resolved from inner and outer queries. But the server cannot resolve any other domain.

What I'm missing?
Can I keep powerdns and configure ubuntu tu use an external dns for any query without the systemd-resolved?

Comment: Because PowerDNS requires even the pdns recursor to be installed. Here you will find the necessary documentation on how to set it up:
https://doc.powerdns.com/authoritative/guides/recursion.html#scenario-2-authoritative-server-as-recursor-for-clients-and-serving-public-domains Just yesterday I managed to put together a fully functional system. Hi,
David

Comment: I don't know if it is a good way, but I managed to solve using my external IP for pdns service and 127.0.0.53 for the internal default ubuntu resolver.